# Entity Framework Inherited Properties not populating

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have in my application a class which inherits properties from a base class which is also mapped to a table using code first.

Everything is working as expect when I look at the database, all values are populated where I expect them to be but my application is crashing.

When inspecting the record retrieved and passed to the view as Model I can see that the owner and creator fields are blank, even though on the inherited table in the database I can see the ID's are populated with a valid user id... Why would these not be getting mapped?

[image: This is the model adding correctly with values populated.]

[image: This is what my view is getting after doing a lookup for the same item id]

BaseClass

```
    public class SiteModel
{
    public SiteModel() { }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string EntityType { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Creator")]
    public int CreatorID;
    public SiteAccount Creator { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Owner")]
    public int OwnerID;
    public SiteAccount Owner { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int? ParentID;
    public SiteModel Parent { get; set; }

    public List<SiteModel> Children { get; set; }

    public SiteModel(SiteAccount creator)
    {
        Creator = creator;
        Owner = creator;
        Created = DateTime.Now;
        EntityType = this.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

Sub Class

```
    [Table("BlogPost")]
public class BlogPost : SiteModel
{
    public BlogPost() { }
    public BlogPost(string title, string content, string description, string tags, BlogCategory category, BlogStatus status, SiteAccount creator) : base(creator)
    {
        Title = title;
        Content = content;
        Description = description;
        Tags = tags;
        Parent = category;
        Status = status;
    }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public BlogStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You may need to change your original problem to fit the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue, Lazy loading was not enabled on the linked properties, To enable this i changed

```
public SiteAccount Creator { get; set; }
```

to

```
public virtual SiteAccount Creator { get; set; }
```

The virtual keyword enabled lazy loading so the navigation properties are fetched whenever the object itself is.